# how to share one object with two logedin users in servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing a servlet based website.

In that servlet, I will receive a request from user. My servlet can perform some user related validations and wait until another user request is received by the same servlet. After that, the servlet will create one shared object between these two users and pass that shared object to two users.

This is my scenario:

```
try {  
    Thread.sleep(10000);  
} catch (InterruptedException e) {  
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe you should hibernate the shared object to a file or database and reload it as you see fit

Comment: Just store the object in application scope and retrieve it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna need a singleton `ConcurrentHashMap` or alike as a store medium where both users' threads have access to.
You can also use some persistent storage in between.